# How assign a qualitative value (flight/feeding) in a column (localization) to some time periods (rows)

Tags: r, datetime, time, filter, period

I would like to fill a column with localisation information (flight / perched / feeding) dependent on the time.

For example, from 13:16:11 to 13:18:32 I know that the bird is flying so I want to put "flight" on the localization column for this period, someone can help me ?

For now, I created a empty column but now I don't know how to fill it.

Thanks, Manon

Answer (score 0):

Is there only 1 bird in your dataframe? You can specify what you want to add to the empty column (here I've called it 'localisation') using the square brackets [], which are used for sub setting. I haven't dealt with time in R for a while, but I think this should work.

`df$localisation[df$time >= "13:16:11" & df$time <= "13:18:32",] <- "flight"`

Comment: Yes I have only one bird for now !

Comment: Thanks you ! I tried your suggestion but I have : "Error in Data_comp$Localisation[Data_comp$UTC_datetime < ymd_hms("2020-02-18 13:18:32"), : 
  incorrect number of clues on the matrix"

Comment: Can you upload a sample dataset to your question? If you can I'll try the code and see if I can fix it.

Comment: I found a way to go through it, I used : 
Data_comp <- Data_comp %>%
  filter(UTC_datetime >= ymd_hms("2020-02-19 13:53:28") & UTC_datetime < ymd_hms("2020-02-19 13:53:59"))
Data_comp$Localisation <- c("Flight")
str(Data_comp) 
Thanks you very much :)